# backup a single user , password and privileges from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, backup, pgadmin, pg-dump

I am moving a database user form one postgresql  server . I need to take backup of the user name , password and privileges and restore into  another  pgsql server.  I looked into the documentation and the pg_dumpall dump all roles , but there is no option to specify a single user,

So if any one know the command and queries , please let me know

Comment: Use `pg_dumpall -r` and manually edit the result. There is no better way.

Comment: It is not  a  solution , I only need  one user credential.  It looks like I need to query from the db tables

Comment: Yes, that's the best solution then.